# Date/time comparison

Tags: sql, axapta

I want to find the date/time with minimum date/time between records. In a table with multiple records.

Fx.

```
 - 11/11-15 13:00
 - 11/11-15 15:30
 - 11/11-15 16:45 <= (find this record)
 - Timenow (11/11-15 18:33) the current record i want to create but i need to compare the old dates with.
```

I can't create the logic, help !

Thanks

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

this is a great place to start  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a function that returns the difference between two dates, run all the possible dates through this function, then pick the lowest difference.

Something like this (pseudo c code)

```
 int array[numdates];
 for (int i=0;i<numdates;i++)
     array[i]=compareDates(date[index], currentDate);
```

Then you can sort the array so the lowest number is at the beginning (or end) and return that one.