# Multiple UTC date time comparison

Tags: datetime, compare, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have these records in my table:

> 11/11/2015 04:48:05 pm
>   11/11/2015 04:50:58 pm
>   11/11/2015 05:07:17 pm
>   11/11/2015 05:08:32 pm

When i use my DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime(); - todays time

I need to compare the other records with todays time, to find the record which is closest to the current datetime.

I am thinking of using DateTimeUtil::getDifference but i can't make the logic right when there are more then two UTC dateTime.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written so far and the part where you can't make the logic right?

Comment: Also a possible duplicate to [Date/time comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655647/date-time-comparison)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### I succeeded my logic, by using this, thanks though.

```
str                lastUser;
utcDateTime        highest = DateTimeUtil::minValue();

ttsBegin;
while select ItemId, CreatedDate, User  from this
    where this.ItemId == _itemId // && this.ProductType == Options::Changed
    {
      //  info(strFmt("CurrentDate: %2", this.ItemId, this.CreatedDate));
    /*    if(this.CreatedDate < loweste)
        {
            loweste = this.CreatedDate;
        } */
         if(this.CreatedDate > highest)
        {
            highest = this.CreatedDate;
            lastUser = this.User;
        }
     //   info(strFmt("lowest is: %1" , loweste));
     //   info(strFmt("highest is: %1 ", highest));
   /*     if(loweste < highest)
        info(strFmt("highest is: %1" , loweste));
     */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about comparing dates, just sort the records in descending date/time order.

```
select firstonly custTrans order CreatedDateTime desc;
```

This will select the record closest to now, provided someone did not turn the clock into the future.